# Oracle Ranking query

Tags: oracle, rank

Need help to achieve below result:
source data:

*[image]*

Output Expected:

[image]

Query to generate source data:

```
SELECT '43443' AS MSISDN,'Turkey' AS LOC,TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS DATA_DAY FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '43443' AS MSISDN,'Turkey' AS LOC,TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) AS DATA_DAY FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '43443' AS MSISDN,'India' AS LOC,TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) AS DATA_DAY FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '43443' AS MSISDN,'Eng' AS LOC,TRUNC(SYSDATE-3) AS DATA_DAY FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '43446' AS MSISDN,'Eng' AS LOC,TRUNC(SYSDATE-4) AS DATA_DAY FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '43446' AS MSISDN,'India' AS LOC,TRUNC(SYSDATE-5) AS DATA_DAY FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What is the logic? Why eng has 1 and 3 as row number in expected output?

Comment: Please explain logic. Now it looks like ordering by max date descending for each location separately and for each MSISDN. Something like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed44e7e508621ad3105f6c12a529e808).

Comment: @PonderStibbons - Thanks for the quick reply, It was an urgent query and needed a quick solution , thanks for the provided solution it helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Please explain your question better and post your answer, it may help someone. Or delete question.